# What is the equation that is used for rank the user feedback in five stars

Tags: excel, ranking-functions

i have a excel sheet that has the users feedback (Excellent, Very Good, Good,Bad , Very Bad) with numbers for each cell.

what is the equation that i can use to get the rank for each user out of 5 stars.

Comment: The cells have numbers in them?

Comment: If the answer given isnt what you want, I'd write out an example sheet with 5 entries and show how you'd like the result to be showed(before and after)

Answer (score 0):

Say we have a list of people in column **A** and their scores in column **B** where **1** is Excellent and **5** is very bad:

[image]

To assign a unique rank to each person, in **C1** enter:

```
=RANK(B1,$B$1:$B$22,1)+COUNTIF($B$1:$B1,B1)-1
```

and copy down.  To organize the list by rank, in **D1** enter:

```
=INDEX(A:A,MATCH(ROWS($1:1),C:C,0))
```

and copy down:

[image]

As you can see, all the people with a score of **1** are at the top and all those with a **5** score are at the bottom.